# Typeclass instance with row type in instance head?

Tags: typeclass, purescript

While I was playing with PureScript, I found that I wanted to write a typeclass `Sync` that would wait for arbitrary asynchronous values to resolve in the `Aff` monad. The typeclass I wrote looked like this:

```
class Sync s eff a where
  sync :: s -> Aff eff a
```

Now I wanted to create `Sync` instance for a websocket connection, which would wait until the connection was open and available for reading/writing. The instance I wrote looked like this:

```
instance syncConnection :: Sync Connection (ws :: WEBSOCKET | eff) Unit where
  sync (Connection socket) =
    makeAff $ \fail continue ->
      set socket.onopen $ \_ ->
        continue unit
```

However, I got the following type error:

```
Type class instance head is invalid due to use of type

  ( ws :: WEBSOCKET
  | eff
  )

All types appearing in instance declarations must be of the form T a_1 .. a_n, where each type a_i is of the same form.
```

Coming from Haskell, this makes sense to me—it mirrors situations where I would need to enable the `FlexibleInstances` extension, which PureScript does not seem to support, either—but I’m left wondering if I can achieve the genericism I want at all.

I thought that perhaps I could tweak my `Sync` class, then just create a newtype.

```
class Sync s m a where
  sync :: s -> m a

newtype WebSocketAff a = WebSocketAff (Aff (ws :: WEBSOCKET) a)
```

Unfortunately, now I’m stuck yet again because I don’t know of any way to give `WebSocketAff` an instance of `MonadAff` for similar reasons to the ones I encountered at the beginning.

Are there any tricks I could use to get this to work without defeating the purpose of the genericism entirely? Or is that sort of thing currently not really expressible within PureScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since compiler version 0.10.3 you are allowed to use rows in the instance head as long as the row is determined via a FunDep:

e.g.

```
class Sync s eff a | s -> eff where -- FunDep here: eff is determinded via s
  sync :: s -> Eff eff a

data ConsoleSync = ConsoleSync

instance syncWithConsole :: Sync ConsoleSync (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit where
  sync _ = log "hello"

foo :: ∀ eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | eff) Unit
foo = sync ConsoleSync
```

Release Notes v0.10.3: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.10.3

Comment: Wow, thanks for responding to this old question, this is really awesome to find out about. Back when I wrote this question, PS didn’t even support functional dependencies, but this totally solves my use case. Exciting!

Answer (score -1):

I'm on my mobile ATM so I can't test this, but did you try using forall?

`instance syncConnection :: forall eff. Sync Connectionync Connection . . .`

Comment: Yes; not only did it not work, but it seemed to be a *parser* error.